# FactoryGirl : generate sequence for start and end date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

Am trying to define a sequence for `start_date` and `end_date` such that the end_date should be n days ahead of start_date.

```
sequence(:start_date)  { |n| Date.current.beginning_of_year.since(n.days) }
sequence(:end_date)    { |n| generate(:start_date).since(n.days) }
```

But this results in undefined_method error which is expected as generate should be called in factory block

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `generate' for #<FactoryGirl::Syntax::Default::DSL:0xe5351fc>
```

I can also sequence the end_date as

```
sequence(:end_date)    { |n| Date.current.beginning_of_year.ago(n.days) }
```

But this may result in my end_date being behind start_date, which is not expected.

Is there any better way to define the required sequence of start and end date ?

Answer (score 2):

To get random number of days you could do:

```
:start_date DateTime.now  
:end_date (rand(n)+1).from_now
```

Where `n` is the interval, i.e. if you want a number of days between 1 and 60 you will do:

```
(rand(60)+1).from_now
```

Comment: do you mean `(rand(n)+1).days.from_now` ? But I want to make sure its between a year only and not across year.

Comment: i've not enough reputation to reply to the comment you added after @Santosh response. There you asked how to generate a random difference. To be sure to avoid crossing the year you could calculate the number of days passed since 1/1/(current year) and use it in the n parameter of rand() method.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
    start_date Faker::Date.between(5.days.from_now, 55.days.from_now)
    end_date Faker::Date.between(57.days.from_now, 75.days.from_now)
```